# Unable to alter the background color of the Tabhost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Recently, I made a simple application that utilizes a Tabhost.
However, I'm unable to set the color to it . I've set the sample code below. How will I be able to add colors to the current code ? it would be a great help if I can  recieve a tip or help.

```
   Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C0392B"));


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Activity").setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.act_second), res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: You want to give a color to a current tab or others too if they're not selected too?

Comment: Well, I would want to set the color to current tab and the selected ones .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set color of `tabHost` in my `tabChanged` method like:

```
for( int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7392B5"));
    }
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4E4E9C"));
```